# Android Job Scheduler - Schedule Job to execute immediately and exactly once

Tags: android, android-jobscheduler

I am trying to use android job scheduler to schedule a job to execute immediately and exactly once.

```
        JobScheduler jobScheduler = (JobScheduler) context.getSystemService(Context.JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE);

        jobScheduler.cancel(1);

        PersistableBundle bundle = new PersistableBundle();
        bundle.putInt(JobFlags.KEY_PERIODIC_SYNC_JOB, JobFlags.JOB_TYPE_INITIAL_FETCH);

        jobScheduler.schedule(new JobInfo.Builder(1,
                new ComponentName(context, SyncJobLollipop.class))
                .setRequiredNetworkType(JobInfo.NETWORK_TYPE_ANY)
                .setExtras(bundle)
                .setMinimumLatency(10)
                .setOverrideDeadline(24 * 3600 * 1000)
                .build());
```

But it running about 3 4 times. What is wrong here ?

Here is the job class itself:

```
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
public class SyncJobLollipop extends JobService implements JobFinishedListener {

    @Inject
    SyncJobBackend jobBackend;

    private JobParameters jobParameters;

    @Override
    public boolean onStartJob(JobParameters jobParameters) {
        ((MyApplication)getApplication()).getAppComponent().inject(this);
        this.jobParameters = jobParameters;
        PersistableBundle bundle = jobParameters.getExtras();
        int type = bundle.getInt(JobFlags.KEY_PERIODIC_SYNC_JOB);
        jobBackend.onStartJob(type, this);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onStopJob(JobParameters jobParameters) {
        jobBackend.onStopJob();
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onJobFinished(boolean success) {
        jobFinished(jobParameters, !success);
    }

}
```

P.S.: I have checked that I am callig jobFinished with false value each and every time.

Comment: Are you sure `jobScheduler.schedule` is only called once?

Comment: Yes. It's called only once. I am on Android N.

Comment: @dumb_terminal   You have `JobFlags.KEY_PERIODIC_SYNC_JOB` in your bundle which I guess makes it `periodic`

Comment: I agree the name is confusing, but it has nothing to do with making it periodic, all the schedule related codes are posted right here. @Merka

Answer (score 9):

To run the job exactly once, you should run your code in `onStartJob(...)` in a background worker, and remove its callbacks when `onStopJob(...)` is called.

```
public class SyncJobLollipop extends JobService {
    final Handler workHandler = new Handler();
    Runnable workRunnable;

    @Override
    public boolean onStartJob(JobParameters params) {
        workRunnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // do your work here,
                // such as jobBackend.onStartJob(type, this)

                boolean reschedule = false;
                jobFinished(params, reschedule);
            }};
        workHandler.post(workRunnable);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onStopJob(JobParameters params) {
        workHandler.removeCallbacks(workRunnable);
        return false;
    }
}
```

To run it immediately you should set both "minimum latency" and "override deadline" to 1.

```
jobScheduler.schedule(new JobInfo.Builder(1,
            new ComponentName(context, SyncJobLollipop.class))
            .setExtras(bundle)
            .setMinimumLatency(1)
            .setOverrideDeadline(1)
            .build());
```

Please note that the operating system's Doze mode might defer JobScheduler tasks until either a "maintenance period" or the device is awoke in some other way. However, the above code would only be running /outside/ of Doze mode, so the job should be scheduled almost without delay.

Comment: Is onJobStart guranteed to run immediately after invoking jobScheduler.schedule ?

Comment: I've added the part about `setOverrideDeadline` too. Yes it will run immediately.