# Video Processing in background with work manager using ffmpeg

Tags: android, ffmpeg, background-process, android-workmanager, mp4parser

The problem comes when during the video processing user closes the application himself from the task manager then its processing stops.

I am working on video file processing in android using `FFMpeg`, which is working perfectly but when I do close the application during processing from task manager then video processing has stopped working even I added all the work in work manager.

```
    @Override 
public Result doWork() {
        shellCommand = new ShellCommand();
        ffmpegBinary = new String[] {
            FileUtils.getFFmpeg(context).getAbsolutePath()
        };
        command = concatenate(ffmpegBinary, command);
        CommandResult commandResult = getCommandResult(command);
        if (command`enter code here`Result.success) {
            onSuccess(videoPath);
        } else {
            onFailure(videoPath);
        }
    }
    //getCommandResult
    private CommandResult getCommandResult(String[] command) {
        try {
            process = shellCommand.run(command, null);
    
            if (process == null) {
                return CommandResult.getDummyFailureResponse();
            }
            checkAndUpdateProcess();
            return CommandResult.getOutputFromProcess(process);
        } catch(Exception e) {} finally {
            Util.destroyProcess(process);
        }
        return CommandResult.getDummyFailureResponse();
    }
```

As far as I can tell, when the application closes from the background then the parent process destroys it and is destroying all of its sub-process too, `FFMpeg` is using the android process to execute the command and check the video file status during video processing.

Looking forward to hear from you.
Thanks

Comment: include the link for the library. naser joooon

Comment: If the application is Force stopped, there's little that WorkManager can do as that action stops all the work till the app is restarted by the user.

Comment: As [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52605503/192373) explains, this behavior may happen on some devices, but cannot be relied upon.

Comment: Have you found any solution yet? Please let me know @Naseer Attari