# Deleting room db records after few days

Tags: android

I have a room db where i saved my data , i want to delete that data after 5 days , starting from the date it was saved , is there anyway to do that guys , thank you

this is my room db deletion query

```
 @Query("DELETE FROM sporttable ")
    void deletedata(LiveModel list);
```

to be more clear : if data has been in 2019-10-24 , by 2019-10-29 i want it to be deleted , thank you guys

Comment: use workmanager and keep log of the date when the data is saved and check logs everyday via workmanager by defining work and if it's 10 then delete the data.

Comment: thank you for the answer , i have little enquiry , i can use workmanager but i read that in some chinese roms , that the workmanager would be killed and thus the operation will fail , is that true

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50682061/android-is-workmanager-running-when-app-is-closed have a look the situations when it stops working

Comment: Thank you much for the answer

Comment: is it possible also using a query in the room db !

Comment: Yes it is. write down query to fetch data and if you want to use variables, use it with :variablename and pass it as a parameter in a function.

Comment: i tried this query but still not giving me anything , can you please tell me your opinion , here is my query   @Query("DELETE FROM livetable WHERE saved_match <= date('now','-1 day')")
    void deleteddata();

Comment: The return type of a function is void, change it to appropriate datatype

Comment: deletion methods requires void or int as a return type , anf for me i want to delete the whole items in my room db , so should i pass the number of rows to delete though the rows number is not garanteed to be the same fix one each time

Comment: You can pass int as rowNumbers and instead of using Delete use query.

Comment: Passing both actually didnt work , i pass a method that returns void and another time one that returns the int and they both didnt work i dont know where could be the issue exactly