# Unable to make WorkManager tasks survive reboot - Android

Tags: java, android

I'm unable to make WorkManager survive reboot. I want my tasks to be executed automatically even after reboot.

```
My Device is Realme X2 with Android 10.
```

WorkManager is working fine. But the moment i reboot my phone and wait for 15 mins for my tasks to be executed but it simply never executes.

WorkManagerReceiver.java

```
package com.example.surviverebootwm;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

import androidx.work.PeriodicWorkRequest;
import androidx.work.WorkManager;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class WorkManagerReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    WorkManager mWorkManager;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder myWorkBuilder =
                new PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(TestWorker.class,
                        PeriodicWorkRequest.MIN_PERIODIC_INTERVAL_MILLIS,
                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

        PeriodicWorkRequest myWork = myWorkBuilder.build();
        mWorkManager = WorkManager.getInstance(context);
        mWorkManager.enqueue(myWork);
    }
}
```

TestWorker.java

```
package com.example.surviverebootwm;

import android.content.Context;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.provider.Settings;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.work.Worker;
import androidx.work.WorkerParameters;

public class TestWorker extends Worker {

    public TestWorker(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull WorkerParameters workerParams) {
        super(context, workerParams);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Result doWork() {
        MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), Settings.System.DEFAULT_ALARM_ALERT_URI);
        mediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
        mediaPlayer.start();
        return Result.success();
    }
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.surviverebootwm;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.work.ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy;
import androidx.work.PeriodicWorkRequest;
import androidx.work.WorkManager;

import android.os.Bundle;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder myWorkBuilder =
                new PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(TestWorker.class,
                        PeriodicWorkRequest.MIN_PERIODIC_INTERVAL_MILLIS,
                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        PeriodicWorkRequest myWork = myWorkBuilder.build();
        WorkManager.getInstance(MainActivity.this)
                .enqueueUniquePeriodicWork("testworker", ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.KEEP, myWork);

    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.surviverebootwm">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver android:name=".WorkManagerReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: did you check this ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50682061/android-is-workmanager-running-when-app-is-closed

Comment: yeah. but there's no solution to this?

Comment: Did you find any solution?