# Android Work Manager is not working in my oppo phone

Tags: android, android-workmanager, android-background

I wrote this program to sync data with the server. Before checking it with the server. I wrote a program to send notifications every 15 minutes.
My phone is oppo A71
Android version 7.1

The following code is not working when I closed the app.

MainActivity.java

```
    PeriodicWorkRequest periodicWorkRequest = new PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(
            MyPeriodicWork.class,15, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
            .addTag("send data")                .build();

    WorkManager.getInstance().enqueue(periodicWorkRequest);
```

MyPeriodicWork.java

```
public class MyPeriodicWork extends Worker {

    private static final String FILE_NAME = "chata.txt";

    private static final String TAG = "MyPeriodicWork";

    public MyPeriodicWork(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull WorkerParameters workerParams) {
        super(context, workerParams);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Result doWork() {

        showNotif();
        Log.e(TAG,"doWork:work is done");
        return Result.success();
    }

    public void showNotif(){

        Intent intent  = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(),0,intent,0);

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat mdformat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
        String strDate = "Current Time : " + mdformat.format(calendar.getTime());

        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationCompat =   new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext(),"14")
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle("Event Handler")
                .setContentText("Helloo"+strDate)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setAutoCancel(true);


        NotificationManagerCompat notificationManagerCompat = NotificationManagerCompat.from(getApplicationContext());
        notificationManagerCompat.notify(4,notificationCompat.build());
    }

   }
```

Do I need to add some permissions to manifest file. If yes what are those codes.

Comment: Did you see https://dontkillmyapp.com/oppo

Comment: But why other apps working properly. Like facebook. wtapp

Comment: Most manufacturers on that site whitelist popular apps specifically because they know their modifications break how apps expect to work.

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50682061/android-is-workmanager-running-when-app-is-closed

Answer (score 0):

this problem on Chinese custom rom they have blacklisted all app except some big app like Facebook,whatsapp etc etc