# Android (Q) : JobScheduler does not call onStartJob() immediately

Tags: android, android-service, job-scheduling, android-10.0, android-jobscheduler

I have a service that extends the JobService.

```
override fun onStopJob(p0: JobParameters?): Boolean {
    return true
}

override fun onStartJob(params: JobParameters?): Boolean {
    Log.d(TAG,"onStartJob :: $params")
    if (params != null) {
        // Do some work.. 
        jobFinished(params, false)
    }
    return true
}
```

- There is the code to post the job using JobScheduler.

  ```
  val jobScheduler = context.getSystemService(JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE) as JobScheduler
  val componentName = ComponentName(context, AndroidAutoService::class.java)

  val jobId = UUID.randomUUID().hashCode()
  val jobInfo = JobInfo.Builder(jobId, componentName).setOverrideDeadline(0).build()
  Log.d(TAG,"jobInfo :: $jobInfo")
  jobScheduler.schedule(jobInfo)
  ```
- **Expected behaviour** is, when we call  **jobScheduler.schedule(jobInfo)**, it should **trigger the onStartJob()** method immediately.
- **Issue :** After calling schedule(jobInfo), It takes some time (between 8 to 10 seconds ) to trigger onStartJob() job.
- This is not happening all the time

Please any one have any idea, Why Am I facing these issue.? Thanks for your suggestion.!

Comment: What are your expectations based upon? AFAIK, nowhere does it say that `JobScheduler` executes immediately.

Comment: JobScheduler can and will decide when is a good time for your task to be run based on when other tasks are scheduled to be run

Comment: AFAIK, if we use setOverrideDeadline(0), it should execute the job immediately.? If this is not the case then please suggest me any solution.? As per my requirement, I need to execute the job right away.

Comment: Have you tried this https://stackoverflow.com/a/49347214/1443981